# ReactJS material-ui TextField apply css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Im using material-ui with Reactjs. I want to apply on a TextField some custom styles using **css**. Specifically I want to change the color of the TextField underline and TextField label when I click the input.

I know that I could do it inline with the component but I want to use className and css.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Look for `styled-components`.

Comment: which version of material-ui are you using? if you are using v1, then you can check this example https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/

Comment: @talentedandrew Im using 0.19.4

Comment: @talentedandrew In this case, I would prefer to wait to material-ui v1 when the alpha version will released

Answer (score 1):

Since `material-ui` uses inline styles in JS, its not very convinient and easy to do a custom styling of components by css classes, but its still possible with `!important` keyword.

First you need to add cutom css class to `TextField`:

```
<TextField
  id="text-field-default"
  className="text-field-custom"
  defaultValue="Default Value"
/>
```

Then, for example, underline style can be overriden like that:

```
.text-field-custom>input:focus+div>hr {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```